# Let $X$ be a set and $d$ the distance function on $X$ defined by $d(x,x)=0$, $d(x,y)=1$ for $x \neq y$. Prove that each subset of $(X,d)$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

Question:

Let $X$ be a set and $d$ the distance function on $X$ defined by $d(x,x)=0$,  $d(x,y)=1$ for  $x \neq y$. Prove that each subset of $(X,d)$ is open.

I'm having trouble finishing up this proof, here is what I have so far.

Proof:

Let $U\subset X$.  To show that $U$ is open, we must show that $U$ is a neighborhood of all of its points, that is, there is a $\delta >0$ such that:

$B(a;\delta) \subset U$ for some $a \epsilon X$

Since $d(x,x)=0$, we know that $x \epsilon B(a;\delta)$ if $x=a$.

-- Here is where I am stuck.  I want to just choose $\delta >1$ but then that would mean my open ball would no longer be contained in $U$ (or would it?).  If I can find a way to incorporate $d(x,y)=1$, then I could just finish the proof by stating that since $B(a;\delta)$ is a neighborhood of its points, and $B(a;\delta) \subset U$, then that implies the $U$ is also a neighborhood, hence U is open.

Comment: Choose $\delta=1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to say that choosing $\delta>1$ would imply that the ball is no longer contained in the set. Indeed, $B(x,\delta)$ for $\delta>1$ is the entire space! (you should check this if this isn't clear).

Hint: Why don't you try $\delta<1/2$? You know $x\in B(x,\delta)$. Can any other point besides $x$ be in this ball? In other words, are there any point $y\neq x$ such that $d(x,y)<1/2$?

Comment: It is kind of confusing to consider a $B(x,\delta)$ with $\delta < 1/2$.  There is only one point in this ball so is it still open?

Comment: Yep! This was what I was getting at; every singleton $\{x\}$ is open in the discrete metric.